# Creating NextJS web app, problem with adding custom theme to shadcn-ui dark mode theme feature

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm able to add my custom theme button and also load my theme but the button component doesn't reflect the custom theme icon. I also can't switch to any other theme once the custom one is loaded. The icon should reflect since it's from the icon library and the custom theme code is in from globals.css under its own selector. [Shadcn-ui](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/dark-mode/next) uses pre-built theme components for NextJS, so I feel like this should work but I have a feeling I may need to create my own custom theme feature instead of using something existing like this. Appreciate any one's feedback.

```
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import { Moon, Sun, Cat } from "lucide-react"
import { useTheme } from "next-themes"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu"


export function ModeToggle() {
  const { setTheme } = useTheme()
  
  const handleThemeChange = (selectedTheme: string) => {
    console.log(`Changing theme to ${selectedTheme}`)
    setTheme(selectedTheme)
  }

  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="secondary" size="icon">
          <Sun className="h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rotate-0 scale-100 transition-all dark:-rotate-90 dark:scale-0" />
          <Moon className="absolute h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rotate-90 scale-0 transition-all dark:rotate-0 dark:scale-100" />
          <Cat className="absolute h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rotate-90 scale-0 transition-all dark:rotate-0 dark:scale-100"  />
          <span className="sr-only">Toggle theme</span>
        </Button>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleThemeChange("light")}>
          Light
        </DropdownMenuItem>
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleThemeChange("dark")}>
          Dark
        </DropdownMenuItem>
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleThemeChange("scary")}>
          Scary
        </DropdownMenuItem>
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleThemeChange("system")}>
          System
        </DropdownMenuItem>
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  )
}
```

Double checked my code and also tried console logging and can confirm theme buttons attempt to switch once clicked but with no effect. Doesn't appear like anyone else has tried this on the internet so far, so nothing else turning up.